# Cool weather destinations in Europe in August

Tags: europe, hiking

I'm looking for a place to stay with my family in Europe that's

1. not too expensive
2. has relatively cool weather
3. and nice hikes.

Bonus points for somewhere that's a little off the beaten track (if that's even possible in Europe). Last year we were in the Austrian Alps, which was perfect. Item 1 rules out Switzerland and most of Scandinavia. Item 2 rules out most of Europe except high mountains and the north. I thought the Pyrenees would make a good destination but to my surprise despite the altitude they're quite warm in summer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! Please narrow your scope more, as the question is too broad and subject to opinion currently.

Answer (score 3):

As Jonathan wrote it is very subjective but here are my suggestions:

1. Slovakia - Velka Fatra, Nizke Tatry, Slovensky Raj. Beautiful mountains, relatively cheap, even in August should not be too much people there.
2. Poland - Bieszczady. Same as above.

I am not recommending main Tatra mountains because in August they are really crowded.